# How to find basis of $\ker T$ and $\mathrm{Im} T$ for the linear map $T$?

Tags: linear-algebra, proof-verification, linear-transformations

> Find the basis of $\ker T$ and $\mathrm{Im} T$ for the linear map $T:M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2} \to M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2}$ defined as $T(A)=A-A^t$ for all $A \in M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2}$.

Let $A=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}$. Then:
$$
T(A)=\begin{pmatrix} a&b\\c&d \end{pmatrix}-\begin{pmatrix} a&c\\b&d \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&b-c\\c-b&0 \end{pmatrix}\stackrel{R_2 \gets-1\cdot R_2}{=}\begin{pmatrix} 0&b-c\\b-c&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

In order to find $\ker T$ we'll evalute $T(A)=0$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix} 0&b-c\\b-c&0 \end{pmatrix}=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}\Rightarrow b=c \Rightarrow \ker T=span \Biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} \Biggr\}
$$

Thus $\dim(\ker T)=3$.

---

Regarding $\mathrm{Im} T$:
$$
ImT=\Biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0&b-c\\b-c&0 \end{pmatrix} \text{such that}\quad b,c, \in \mathbb R \Biggr\}=span\Biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\1&0 \end{pmatrix} \Biggr\}
$$

Thus $\dim(\mathrm{Im} T)=1$.

Are my calculations correct?

Comment: I reckon $\text{Im}\,T$ is actually generated by $\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0}$.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown so we can't apply elementary operations when calculating $T(A)$?

Comment: the same vector you have for $ImT$ is also at $Ker T$ so you have a mistake there

Comment: when you found $T(A)$ you made a row operation, which is wrong because by that you changed the transformation. when you will solve without it you will get the result lord shark wrote

Comment: @Yos Applying elementary row operations as you did is an isomorphism on $\text{Im }T$, it doesn't preserve the image literally.

Comment: @KenDuna so the correct answer is $\ker T=span \Biggl\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1&0\\0&0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0&1\\-1&0 \end{pmatrix},\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&1 \end{pmatrix} \Biggr\}$?

Comment: @Yos No, your kernel is correct, the image was the problem. Applying elementary row operations does preserve the kernel, but not the image. The correct image is as Lord Shark said.

Comment: @KenDuna because when in order to find the kernel I need to solve a linear system where elementary operations are allowed?

Comment: Thanks to new user @ksf for providing the following input. I feel like it fits better as a comment than an edit to my answer: "When all is said and done, don't forget that the rank-nullity theorem can be a quick and easy way to check your work. Since you're working in the vector space $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, which has dimension 4, you know that the sum of the dimensions for the kernel and the image of T must be 4. This means your original answer is promising at least in terms of the dimensionality, but as mentioned above, you should check the signs on $b-c$ when working with the kernel."

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an answer will help clarify things. You computed that $$T(A) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b-c \\ c-b & 0 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & b-c \\ -(b-c) & 0 \end{pmatrix} = (b-c) \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

From this we see that $\textrm{Im}(T) = \textrm{span}\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}\right\}_.$

We also see that $T(A) = 0$ if and only if $b-c = 0$. In other words when $b=c$. From there you see that $$\ker(T) = \textrm{span}\left\{\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right\}_.$$

Note you shouldn't actually be row reducing $T(A)$, you want that matrix to be zero. You could find the matrix of $T$ with respect to some basis, and row reduce that to find the kernel of $T$.

The reason that row reduction can be used to find the kernel of a matrix is because row reduction corresponds to multiplying on the left by an invertible matrix. This doesn't change the kernel.

---

An alternative approach to the problem. Let us compute the matrix of $T$, call it $B$, with respect to the standard basis of $M_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$, $\left\{ \begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}, \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix}\right\}_.$

$$T\left(\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_. $$

$$T\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_. $$

$$T\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & -1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_. $$

$$T\left(\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix} \right) = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_. $$

Using this, we calculate that $$ B = \begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 & 0 & 0\\ 0 & 1 & -1 & 0 \\ 0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\ 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix}_.$$

You could row reduce this or just see by inspection that $A \in \ker (T)$ precisely when $b = c$.

Comment: Your second approach comes very handy if I need to check if $T$ is diagonizable! Because I get the $[T]_E$ matrix representation

Answer (score 1):

You can use the fact that every square matrix is, in a unique way, the sum of a symmetric and an antisymmetric matrices.

Any symmetric matrix belongs to the kernel of $T$, whereas the antisymmetric matrix
$$
A=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ -1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$
does not belong to $\ker T$. Since the space of symmetric matrices has dimension $3$, with basis
$$
\left\{
\begin{pmatrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 0 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \end{pmatrix},
\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
\right\}
$$
this is also a basis for $\ker T$.

A basis of the image consists of
$$
T(A)=\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 2 \\ -2 & 0 \end{pmatrix}
$$