# How to find the diagonizable matrix of the linear map $T:M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2} \to M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2}$ defined as $T(A)=A-A^t$?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, linear-transformations

> Let linear map $T:M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2} \to M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2}$ defined as $T(A)=A-A^t$ for all $A \in M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2}$. Find the diagonizable matrix $D$ and the matrix $P$ which makes $A$ diagonizable.

This question builds on this post: [How to find basis of $\ker T$ and $\mathrm{Im} T$ for the linear map $T$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2338390/how-to-find-basis-of-ker-t-and-mathrmim-t-for-the-linear-map-t).

We can build the matrix representation for $T$ according to the standard basis $E$:
$$
[T]_E=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\0&1&-1&0\\0&-1&1&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}
$$

Hence in order to find the eigenvalues we need the calculate the determinant of the following matrix:
$$
\det(tI-[T]_E)=\det \begin{pmatrix} t&0&0&0\\0&t-1&1&0\\0&1&t-1&0\\0&0&0&t \end{pmatrix}=t^3(t-2)
$$
Therefore we have 2 eigenvalues $t_1=0$ and $t_2=2$. Because the algebraic and geometric (this can be seen in the question I referenced above) multiplicities are equal there's a diagonizable matrix.

What I'm not sure is how to write $D$ and $P$.

Should $D$ be like this:
$$
D=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix} \quad \text{or in the}\quad M^{\mathbb R}_{2 \times 2} \quad \text{format} \quad D=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&2 \end{pmatrix}
$$

After plugging in the eigenvalues instead of $t$'s above I got that the subspace for $t_1=0$ is $span\{(1,1)\}$ while the subspace for $t_2=2$ is $span\{(-1,1)\}$.

So should $P$ be:
$$
P=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&-1 \end{pmatrix}
$$
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solution handles the $\mathbb{K}$-linear operator $T:\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})\to\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ over a field $\mathbb{K}$ of characteristic not equal to $2$.  Suppose that $\lambda\in\mathbb{K}$ is an eigenvalue of $T$ with an eigenvector $A\in\text{Mat}_{n\times n}(\mathbb{K})$ with $A\neq 0$.  Then, $T(A)=\lambda A$ implies that $(1-\lambda)A=A^\top$, so $$A=\left(A^\top\right)^\top=\big((1-\lambda)A\big)^\top=(1-\lambda)\,A^\top=(1-\lambda)^2\,A\,.$$
Therefore, $\lambda\,\left(\lambda-2\right)=0$, or $\lambda\in\{0,2\}$.

If $\lambda=0$, then $A$ is a symmetric matrix.  If $\lambda=2$, then $A$ is an skew-symmetric matrix.  Since the subspace consisting of symmetric matrices is $\frac{n(n+1)}{2}$-dimensional and the subspace consisting of skew-symmetric matrices is $\frac{n(n-1)}{2}$-dimensional, $T$ is diagonalizable.  In fact, every $X\in\text{Mat}_{n \times n}(\mathbb{K})$ can be written as
$$X=X_\text{sym}+X_{\text{skew}}\,,$$
with $X_\text{sym}:=\frac{A+A^\top}{2}$ and $X_\text{skew}:=\frac{A-A^\top}{2}$.  Then,
$$T(X)=2\,X_{\text{skew}}\,.$$

It is an interesting exercise to find a Jordan canonical form of $T$ in the case where $\text{char}(\mathbb{K})=2$.  The eigenspace with the eigenvalue $0=2$ is still the subspace consisting of symmetric matrices.

Comment: Should I write $D=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0&0&0\\0&0&0&0\\0&0&2&0\\0&0&0&0 \end{pmatrix}$ or $D=\begin{pmatrix} 0&0\\0&2 \end{pmatrix}$?

Comment: Well, $V:=\text{Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R})$ is $4$-dimensional, so a matrix of $T$ in any basis of $V$ is going to be $4$-by-$4$.

Comment: And regarding $P$ will it be $$
P=\begin{pmatrix} 1&1\\1&-1 \end{pmatrix}
$$?